# Limit and measure VSS/RSS

Tags: memory, c

I'm writing a program on Ubuntu 16.04, and it will `fork`, do some setups and `exec` another program. I need to:

1. Limit the maximum VSS the program could use
2. Limit the maximum RSS the program could use
3. Measure the maximum VSS the program used during its execution
4. Measure the maximum RSS the program used during its execution

So far I can do 1. and 4. as following:

```c
pid_t chpid = fork();
if (!chpid) {
    // I do lots of setup here
    struct rlimit rlim;
    rlim.rlim_cur = rlim.rlim_max = limit_VSS;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &rlim); // 1.
    execv(path, args);
}
struct rusage stats;
wait3(NULL, 0, &stats);
long max_RSS = stats.ru_maxrss;  // 4.
```

How can I implement 2. and 3.?

The `RLIMIT_RSS` option in `setrlimit` seems not useful, and I don't know how to get `VmPeak` in `/proc/pid/status` after the process is terminated (or right before the process terminates).

I need a efficient way, i.e., not having a significant impact on the `exec` program. (There are `ptrace` and some tools such as `valgrind`, but it will slow down the execution a lot.)

Comment: Sorry, what is VSS and RSS?

Comment: @datUser Virtual Set Size and Resident Set Size. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372960/is-this-explanation-about-vss-rss-pss-uss-accurate).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about separating out VSS from RSS usage, but you could look at using memory pools, or using a malloc substitute which monitors and/or enforces maximum allocation from the system.

Take a look at the taskstats process accounting package.  It doesn't record final memory usage, but does record High watermark of RSS usage and VM usage, which may be what you want anyway?  I'm not sure if it's available as standard with Ubuntu's 16.04 kernels - you may need to build a kernel module to get it.